# GraphServiceClient get group from name

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to find all members of a given group, and I only have the group name (and not the id). Is there anyway to get a group from name with the GraphServiceClient? Onlything I found requires id:

```
var users = await graphClient.Groups[group.Id].Members.Request().GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can the filter the groups using query parameter and search the Group by using DisplayName. For example - you can search the groups whose displayName starts with 'test' like below:

```
var result = await client.Groups.Request().Filter("startswith(displayName,'Test')").Select("displayName,description,id").GetAsync();
```

Comment: This gives me `Code: BadRequest
Message: Invalid filter clause`

Comment: @Bassie I had the same issue with my filter but had to encode the value i was using to filter with like "var urlEncodedFilterValue = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filterValue);"

Answer (score 0):

The method suggested by SaurabhSharma didn't work for me. Looking at this updated [MSFT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=python#request-3), their suggestion is:

```py
query_params = GroupsRequestBuilder.GroupsRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
        filter = "startswith(displayName, 'Test')",
        count = True,
        top = 1,
        orderby = ["displayName"],
)

request_configuration = GroupsRequestBuilder.GroupsRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
query_parameters = query_params,
)
request_configuration.headers.add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")


result = await client.groups.get(request_configuration = request_configuration)
```

Hope this helps!